# how to convert multiple joins to rails query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i want to write this query into active record method query

```
SELECT properties.name ,fields.name ,field_values.value FROM properties
 LEFT JOIN fields 
ON properties.company_id=fields.company_id AND fields.required_model='Property'
LEFT JOIN field_values
ON field_values.field_id=fields.id  AND field_values.field_id=fields.id AND 
field_values.fieldable_id=properties.id;
```

and if I simplify this query bit more

```
SELECT  fields.name ,field_values.value FROM fields 
LEFT JOIN field_values
ON field_values.field_id=fields.id AND 
field_values.fieldable_id=4892
 where
fields.company_id=3 AND fields.required_model='Property';
```

I want to use this in the property serializer, where I'm trying something like this

```
object.company.fields.join("LEFT JOIN field_values ON 
field_values.field_id=fields.id AND 
field_values.fieldable_id=4892").where(required_model: 
'Property')
```

but join in this is not working.

Comment: Always show what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if rails allows to select columns in that manner. we can try another way, but will return array of hash containing column we need

```
query = <<~SQL.squish
  SELECT properties.name AS properties_name, fields.name AS fields_name ,field_values.value as fields_value
  FROM properties
  LEFT JOIN fields
  ON (
    properties.company_id=fields.company_id AND 
    fields.required_model='Property'
  )
    LEFT JOIN field_values
    ON (
      field_values.field_id=fields.id AND 
      field_values.field_id=fields.id AND
      field_values.fieldable_id=properties.id
    )
SQL
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query).to_hash
```

result will be array of hash like below example

```
[
  {
    "properties_name"=>"PROPERTY_NAME", "fields_name"=>"FIELDS_NAME", "fields_value"=>"FIELDS_VALUE"
  }
  {
    "properties_name"=>"PROPERTY_NAME", "fields_name"=>"FIELDS_NAME", "fields_value"=>"FIELDS_VALUE"
  }
]
```

Can you try above once?

Comment: yeah it can work perfectly , but I want to use this in property serializer , where join like this is not working

Comment: i've updated my question please have a look

Comment: what is the error you are getting?? also in your property serializer query (`object.company.fields.join`), is will be **joins** instead of join

Comment: thanks that is working now , but there is a problem , field_values.fieldable_id=object.id 
in this line object.id is not working 
  missing FROM-clause entry for table "object"
LINE 1: ....field_id=fields.id AND field_values.fieldable_id=object.id ...

Comment: can you add error in question itself as i am not able to understand the error in comment. It's ok if you add error screenshot itself

Comment: thank you it is solved actually , I was passing object.id in string and wasn't applying interpolation

Comment: ohh great!! You solved question by yourself :)